# Make my custom program root

Tags: root, chmod, chown

I have a custom program in C, that iterates trough a directory and writes a log file with the contents in my home. However, it cannot acces /var/log/ /etc/ and other root folders. How to change that? It`s currently chowned by a non root user chown myname:myname myprogram. Any info how to make it root-a-like?

Answer (score 4):

If you want a program to run as root, start it as root. Either login as root or use `su` or `sudo`.

The owner is irrelevant unless the `setuid` flag is set. Be aware though: `setuid` can be *very* dangerous because it will always run as root (or whatever user owns the file). If your program contains vulnerabilities, an attacker could use it to gain complete control of the system. Also, if the file is not contained in a protected directory, a user with directory write permissions can change owners as he likes.

Use `chmod 4xxx <file>` (where `xxx` is the “regular” mode) to set the `setuid` flag. Modern implementations also support `chmod u+s <file>`

Comment: I`ve ran it as root. The program misses completely /var/log/ dir due to permission issues. My program is chmod-ed with u+x and is in the /usr/local/bin/

Comment: If your running the program as root, then its not a permission issue, that's preventing the program from iterating through that folder.

Comment: OK, then what? Somehting distro dependant? Fedora 21 is what I use.

Comment: @IlianZapryanov if you start a shell as root, can you see inside /var/log?

Comment: @dsolimano Yes, /var/log is shown normal.

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/heatblazer/16272667525/
This is the screenshot, as you see /var/log is set for iterating but nothing happens

Comment: Actually now, as I ran it with # shell it was OK, showed the /var/log/ but skipped /etc/

Comment: What's the error you get when your program attempts to read /etc?  This is beginning to look like a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Let me double check again and my C code. It`s daemon in C with Qt visualization as it seems, to purge directories at fixed intervals. So let me see if I don`t have some code errors.

Comment: OK, confirmed, that the program does not delete folders, for which I don`t have permission. But some folders from the var were removed.